# Get all the friends of friends list

Tags: mysql

I have a table "friendship" like this

```
user_id
friend_id
```

For each friendship I make one record instead of two.

```
---------------------
user_id | friend_id |
--------------------
  1     |   2       |
--------------------
```

And I Don't add  (2 , 1) into table.
So, I need to get all the friends of friends list including those who are already in my friend list preferably without subqueries. Any suggestions ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't add `2, 1` ?

Comment: And... is there any reason for no subqueries? That's like going to MacDonalds and pretending there are no burgers.

Comment: @webarto I think reason is simple. You table size in this case is less in two times.

Comment: @Glenn I think answer of your question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT f2.friend_id
  FROM friendship f1 JOIN friendship f2
    ON f1.friend_id = f2.user_id 
 WHERE f1.user_id = 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31f49/3)** demo

Comment: What if you want to get *friends of friends* for user 3 in your current fiddle? 3 has 2 as friend (per table design).

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work correct , if you will insert in your table pair like this (2,1) instead (1,2)..